# c++ Passing var from function to function then display result in main function

Tags: c++, function, variables, pass-by-value

How do I pass the user entered distance gathered from one function to another function to calculate a shipping cost? And then show the cost via the int main function?

My distance function

```
double getDistance(double distance)
{
cout << "Enter the distance to be shipped: (min 10 Mi, max 3000 Mi): ";
cin >> distance;
while(distance<=10 || distance>= 3000){
    cout << "We do not ship less than 10 miles or more than 3000 miles, 
please reenter: ";
    cin >> distance;
}
return distance;
}
```

I was thinking I could return distance and then use it in another function?? Is that right?

I need the variable distance to calculate the final shipping cost in another function ie calcCost then in the main function int main() simply display it cout << "the cost is " << finalCost << endl;

How do I pass the variable distance to another function to calculate cost and then display the cost via the int main() function?

Comment: It sounds like you already know what to do.

Comment: "*I was thinking I could return distance and then use it in another function??*" Did you try it? What went wrong?

Comment: Practice practice practice ... best way to understand methods, variables, passing them, returning them etc..

Comment: @scohe001 thats the thing i dont know how

Comment: @miradulo its "How do I pass the variable distance to another function to calculate cost and then display the cost via the int main() function?"

Comment: Well try. And if you have a _specific issue_ that you can't figure out, you can ask about that.

Comment: @miradulo i got too few arguments to function calcCost https://imgur.com/a/xajMF

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the returned value of distance in the main function as a parameter for another function:

```
int main(){
distance= getDistance();
finalCost = calculatefinalCost(distance);
..
}
```

By the way: you don't need a parameter in getDistance, the value will be replace by the user input anyway.